# onActivityResult in the main activity is not called even though the sub-activity executes setResult() and finish()

Tags: android

I have written a simple app which has an 'About' screen (activity) that is shown when the user selects the 'About' item in the Options Menu from the main activity. The 'About' screen has a button named 'Close' on it.

The behaviour I want is that when the user clicks the 'Close' button, she/he should be taken to the previous activity (i.e. the activity from which the About activity was launched). For this I launch the About activity (TFTAbout) from the main activity (TFT) using `startActivityForResult();` then in `TFTAbout.java` I invoke `setResult()` and `finish()`, which should in turn invoke `onActivityResult()` in the main activity when I click 'Close'.

What actually happens is that when I click 'Close' the main activity (TFT) is not called.

From the logs it appears that the activity TFTAbout does execute `setResult()` and `finish()`. However, at this very point, onDestroy is called for the main activity. So, my guess is that since there is no launching activity to return to, `onActivityResult()` is not being called. 
Am I right?

---

Please refer to Logcat output below (without timestamps for better readabiliy):

```
DEBUG/TFT(816): onOptionsItemSelected: 'About' item selected.

INFO/ActivityManager(563): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT type=text/plain comp={com.wirel.tft/com.wirel.tft.TFTAbout} }

DEBUG/TFTAbout(816): onCreate: START

DEBUG/TFTAbout(816): onCreate: END

INFO/ActivityManager(563): Displayed activity com.wirel.tft/.TFTAbout: 3880 ms

DEBUG/TFT(816): onDestroy: BEGIN

DEBUG/TFT(816): onDestroy: END

DEBUG/dalvikvm(606): GC freed 672 objects / 36656 bytes in 90ms

DEBUG/TFTAbout(816): onClick: 'Close' button pressed... Returning to calling activity.

WARN/ActivityManager(563): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4370efe0 {com.wirel.tft/com.wirel.tft.TFTAbout}}

WARN/ActivityManager(563): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4370efe0 {com.wirel.tft/com.wirel.tft.TFTAbout}}

DEBUG/TFTAbout(816): onClick: Activity is finishing? true
```

---

Code of the lauching activity (TFT):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem mi ) 
{
    int item_id = mi.getItemId();
    switch ( item_id )
    {
        case R.id.mi_about:
        {
            Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onOptionsItemSelected: 'About' selected." );
            /* Start the activity to display the About page. */
            Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,
                                   TFTMetadata.ABOUT_TEXT_URI );
            i.setType( "text/plain" );

            startActivityForResult( i, 0 );
            break;
        }
        ....
 }


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult
        ( int request_code, int result_code, Intent i )
{
    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult: START." );

    super.onActivityResult( request_code, result_code, i );

    /* Use the request code to select between multiple child activities we may have started. Here there is only one thing we launch. */

    if ( request_code == Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER )
    {
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onActivityResult: 'About' activity has returned." );
    }
}
```

Code of the launched activity (TFTAbout):

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onCreate: START" );

    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );

    /* Set what to do when the user presses a key but the key press is
     not handled by the application. */
    setDefaultKeyMode( DEFAULT_KEYS_DISABLE );

    /* Connect the appropriate resource to this activity. */
    setContentView( R.layout.about );

    /* Define the click listener for the Close button. */
    Button b = (Button) findViewById( R.id.bt_close );
    b.setOnClickListener( this );      
}


public void onClick(View v) 
{
    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onClick: 'Close' button pressed... Returning to calling activity." );
    setResult( RESULT_OK, (new Intent()).setAction("About activity has finished!") );

    finish();

    ComponentName cn = this.getCallingActivity();
    if ( cn != null )
    {
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onClick: calling activity = " + cn.getClassName() );
    }
    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onClick: Activity is finishing? " + String.valueOf( this.isFinishing() ) );

    return;
}
```

Could somebody please explain to me why my main activity might be getting destroyed, and whether what I am doing is correct?

Comment: I have decided to replace the additional activity with a simple dialog instead. This serves my purpose perfectly without having to deal with a new activity. I should have tried this the first time.
Thanks, anyway.

If anybody has any suggestions, please add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same problem. In my case I solved this by changing a line in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Please see [MainActivity does not receive result from StartActivityForResult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17464574/mainactivity-does-not-receive-result-from-startactivityforresult/20976255#20976255)

I hope this will solve your problem.