# MainActivity does not receive result from StartActivityForResult

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have the following common problem, easy, yet I don't know what more I can do.
I have the MainActivity that starts for result AnotherActivity.

In the `MainActivity` I have (extends `Activity`):

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Altele.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Toast something; //toast NOT showing
    webview.loadUrl(data.getStringExtra("adresa"));
}
```

In the `AnotherActivity` I have (extends `ListActivity`):

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Toast something; //toast showing
    Intent intentMessage = new Intent();        
    intentMessage.putExtra("adresa", something);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, intentMessage);
    finish();       
}
```

Now, whatever I do, the data from `AnotherActivity` doesn't seem to reach the `MainActivity`. In this sample here, I skipped on purpose the `requestCode` and `resultCode` since it's the same thing. So what I have here, is basically all over the internet, but to me it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Source code: http://www3.zippyshare.com/v/13090519/file.html

**UPDATE**
i've noticed a thing. if i start my second activity for result as soon as the application starts, it's onActivityResult in the main activity gets triggered. if i wait 2 seconds after application's start or try again running the second activity for result, nothing happens anymore.

Comment: instead of Toast ,try printing a log in your main activity, toast most probably is not showing because it is not in UI Thread.

Comment: i put the toast just to see if it reaches that step in the code. even if log using, still it doesn't receive any data.

Comment: Is the AnotherActivity your Altele.class? If not, then that's the reason your code isn't working.

Comment: yes, another is altele. i tried to use english to make it easier to read and understand for others.

Comment: What happens if we dont extend activity ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a "putExtra" and trying to get a "getStringExtra". You should either use "putStringExtra" or "getExtra".

Comment: there is not "getStringExtra" or "getExtra". i can't seem to have other choices.

Comment: @user2015552 `myIntent.getExtras().getString(key)`

Comment: no, somehow it doesn't call onActivityResult. here is the project http://www3.zippyshare.com/v/13090519/file.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this one

```
startActivityForResult(i, **2**);
```

.
.
.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    switch (requestCode) {
     case **2**:
        toast something;//toast NOT showing
        webview.loadUrl(data.getStringExtra("adresa"));
     break;
    }
}
```

In the list view You can change it as

```
setResult(0, (new Intent()).setAction(i.getStringExtra("String")));
```

Comment: did you tried by keeping the Syso(); in OnActivityResult or  Just try to send a string like setResult(0,"abc");

Comment: if (resultCode == 0) {
} else {
     if (intent != null) {

Comment: yes, i did all possible tests. the idea is that the second activity does not pass anything to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done seems to be correct. I have tried and it works for me.. I am sharing sample code I have written. Hope this helps.

My MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); 
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("abcd");
        Toast.makeText(this, data.getStringExtra("abc"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1){
             Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity1.class);
             startActivityForResult(in, 1);
        }

    }

}
```

My MainActivity1 which extends ListActivity
It works very fine and prints out put in ddms and also toast message

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity1 extends ListActivity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
      }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Intent intentMessage=new Intent();        
        intentMessage.putExtra("abc","def");
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intentMessage);
        finish();       
    }

}
```

Comment: no, it's impossible... but why would it work for you, but not for me? ... it's the same code after all...

Comment: Its simple code after all... I don't understand why it is not working... Kindly copy above code and try once because it works perfectly... Be sure you are not doing any silly mistakes... Keep sysout instead of toast message and try first..

Comment: copied (made a new activity for it), but not working either. and i know the code is correct :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your manifest file doesn't contain singletask for the activity you are starting from.

Comment: hmmm... please explain. both main and another activities are added to the manifest, but as eclipse added them when they were created. would there be something else to add to their declarations?

Comment: In your MainActivity OR Altele class declaration what are the code written in manifest.

Comment: <activity
            android:name="ro.pca.asigurarionline.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="ro.pca.asigurarionline.Altele"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_altele" >
        </activity>

Answer (score 0):

May these help you..

Instead of using `INTENT` to pass data between your activity try to use `SharedPreference`

It can store data and data can be retrieved easily..

Hope these will help you..

Comment: and how do i notify the first activity that i saved data?

Comment: Buddy you dont have to notify the first activity.. whenever you save the data in sharedpreference in current activity call finish() method and collect the saved data in onActivityResult() in First Activity..

Comment: yes buddy, but if i wait for onActivityResult, i'm back where i started at. onActivityResult doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

A late answer, but probably useful at someone. I had the same problem, when I noticed that in the definition of MainActivity in AndroidManifest.xml file I had the line

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

The problem disappeared when I correct this line to

```
android:noHistory="false"
```

In fact you may also delete the whole line (see [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)) 
Hope this will work also for you.